# Background for button not updating - Andorid

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-button, material-components-android

In my Android project, I have a button with a background of purple, but it is showing blue.

[image: Button Error]

This is my code:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:background="@color/blue">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_StartGame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/purple"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/start_game" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    
</LinearLayout>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="lawnGreen">#7CFC00</color>
    <color name="neonGreen">#39FF14</color>
    <color name="cyan">#00FFFF</color>
    <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
    <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
    <color name="purple">#800080</color>
    <color name="pink">#EE82EE</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MultiSmart" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/purple</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

themes.xml (night)

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MultiSmart" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/purple</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

I didn't provide `MainActivity.java` because I didn't customize it yet, it's just a new project.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Cause:

The `android:background` doesn't show up the right color in the button because when using a material components theme; there is a default tint color applied (i.e. it's not `null` like in the previous `AppCompat` themes), and it affects the button color.

### Solution:

You can solve this by applying one of a couple of ways to the button:

- Use `android:backgroundTint` instead of `android:background`
- Set the tint to null with `app:backgroundTint="@null"`, and normally use `android:background`